# How to enrich harmonics in audio?

Tags: waveform, harmonics, guitar-pedal

I'm designing a guitar pedal to boost harmonics in the signal here: [Falstad Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBsB0Z-CEEYCmBaA7CJZoCY48MMBmMADj0gE5qsBWCekAFhJHvSSQCgAlEGiSQQBcoPIQx4bKxYRcSGQuj0eAY1EY8ovCy06iOqbERn4edFlwVakenSTVySeiyLXTvAOYG-RkDJ9BR4Ad389UXJxPEiwHgB5QPJ9WP0WFhi48B4AJ1EKXVTtIplXOB4AEwKs1MK8ehEdJAA5egxuKuxqQ0buw0jmto7ecKcButqc8OkGkXHRPvixvCmFtJz5alY11dKlXBE0cmhyEkgzsD16JCIMkRs8EgOeX0zReR2o8RCBSX6QP9bj8ZJ9tgpwKp+ICpH1-iRzspWBA0ODlFCxj19ljuMYwl9gV9pMtvqUEU04q8aqTpEFlHlBMJqe9iawMAyhE1Cpy-BB5PAqTyAkLovSZvU+rNRfFqgtcTDsLdRNhhp1qv9qPMsZrla12p1MTodXKlSSNSIgaaGeSyYiAhAcBVfDaAja6SF8iQUraKcFsALNC7Cl7JqDoBh0OIkKoLk5CLFLuSuMwbGBRslQyHSiSg+IXZSkBh9Eyde9hA7-XBIXBmAAZFAANxQABt8SWLRAdWbOx2FfF8v8gVj-g6cG3hw7tQ8eAB7VhQP23PDUFSrDBgC56SCkEg9aWmNNlWcySCL2LUA6wWjX6-kUiQbgsS8157RB-0AgOagsZyyYyBHggA)

I'm wondering if there are ways to boost harmonics that don't clip the signal, as well as any adjustments I should make to maintain a clean tone, (the point is a clean harmonic boost, I would like to avoid hard-clipping distortion and heavy gain)

**Edit:** I simulated the circuit in Falstad, and It's a rather nice crunch tone. [Sound sample](https://soundcloud.com/daniel-oren-ibarra-313250256/audio-20220428-1414circuitjs?utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing)

Comment: I think you're describing a multi-band compressor.

Comment: Adding harmonic is distortion, so adding one always gives you the other.

Comment: @user1850479 More specifically, I want to avoid hard clipping, I probably should have said that instead.

Comment: You should use a monotonic "analog" "non-linear function", should be also "symmetrical. NB: can be also a non-linear "digital" multiplier. It must maintain the "fundamental" of the input "signal".

Comment: If you are ready to make some electronic circuit with transistors and diodes and resistors and capacitors you can easily introduce some distortion using a signal path going through some diodes. One problem with the example is that you got two diodes connected to a low impedance source (OpAmp). That is a bad design. It will create erratic behavior due to current saturation of the OpAmp, possibly catastrophic in a long term. But the idea of the two diodes in the feedback loop is a great approach for distortion. You could also use two channels and mix them to adjust the effect.

Comment: Transformer distortion seems popular in audio applications, a small audio transformer driven slightly into saturation can provide some nice harmonics.

Comment: @FredCailloux are you talking about the diodes in the feedback loop of the opamp, or the hard clipping diodes before the RC network? (Note, the diodes in the feedback loop are stolen almost directly from the Ibanez tube screamer schematic)

Comment: I'm talking about the two diodes between the OpAmp output and GND. Putting a 1k resistor between the output and the two diodes will correct the situation providing that the OpAmp is capable of driving a 1k ohms load, which is quite possible ( refer to OpAmp datasheet to make certain ).  Also, I like John D idea about audio transformers for distortion source. A small audio transformer into saturation will certainly provide some great distortion. All these ideas can be implemented in parallel by driving the input signal into different distortion circuits and adjusting with some potentimeters.

Comment: Take a look here    https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/437482551295569939/

Comment: https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/9148005484762720/

Comment: NB: note that when you apply "distortion", cross-modulation can appear and this is not only enriched "harmonic" levels ...

Comment: There's one sure-fire way to do this....   (Add pleasing harmonics w/o hard clipping)     Get a tube preamp!!!!

Comment: Your "crunch" demo has plenty of hard clipping because you can see that all its peak levels are at the same peak clipping level. The hardness is softened by filtering away the highest frequencies.

Answer (score 3):

A clean harmonic boost doesn't exist.

THD (total harmonic distortion) is a measure for distortion and clean Hifi enthusiasts aim to minimize THD as far as possible.

With respect to audio there are various simple ways to add distortion and create characteristic sound. Such as diode clipping and transformer saturation or using no feedback to linearize amplification stages. It's down to taste but one thing the "nice" distortions do all have in common:

They are prevented from producing very high order harmonics but only low index ones mostly. This is achieved by using only slight nonlinearities.ass opposed to e.g. hard clipping without filtering.